# StandardScaler: TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am using StandardScaler to scaling my dataframe like below, and I got an error of ypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'. I am not sure where is the problem? Thanks for your help.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from random import randrange
import random
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler # for feature scaling

random.seed(10)

df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0,50):
    df = df.append({'x': randrange(1,10),
                    'y': randrange(10,21),
                    'depth':randrange(400,601)}, ignore_index=True)
df.head()


depth   x   y
0   523.0   1.0 16.0
1   518.0   1.0 13.0
2   567.0   8.0 14.0
3   533.0   3.0 10.0
4   419.0   8.0 15.0

scaler = StandardScaler

scaler.fit(df)
df_scaled= scaler.transform(df)
```

The error  is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-98ea46087b3f> in <module>
      4 scaler = StandardScaler
      5 
----> 6 scaler.fit(df)
      7 df_scaled= scaler.transform(df)

TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'
```

Comment: Same error with `scaler.fit(X=df)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
```

You forgot the parenthesis